# Is it possible to use PlatformView without adding Android plugin in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I have a `PlatformView` for displaying map in my Flutter application. The platform view is located in the plugin so it has access to `PluginRegistry` and can register platform view using method `PlatformViewRegistry platformViewRegistry()`.

However, I would like to move it form the plugin to the main project in order to keep everything in a single project.

Is that possible, how should I access `platformViewRegistry` in that case?

Answer (score 5):

I did it like this, using the `flutterEngine` reference that you get in your main activity to obtain a registry:

### In your main activity

```
 override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        YourPlugin.registerWith(flutterEngine)
 }
```

### YourPlugin would then be

```
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine

object YourPlugin{
    fun registerWith(engine: FlutterEngine) {
        engine
            .platformViewsController.registry
            .registerViewFactory(
                YourView.VIEW_NAME, YourViewFactory(engine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger))
    }
}
```

### And finally a factory like this

```
import android.content.Context
import io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger
import io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec
import io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformView
import io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewFactory

class YourViewFactory(private val messenger: BinaryMessenger) : PlatformViewFactory(StandardMessageCodec.INSTANCE) {

    override fun create(context: Context, id: Int, o: Any?): PlatformView {
        return YourView(context, messenger, id)
    }
}
```